# Cannot get Window Session Manager to work

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell-extension

I installed the Window Session Manager under Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and probably got something wrong. I then executed the instructions in the [Git repository](https://github.com/johannesjo/gnome-shell-extension-window-session-manager), but still no luck: when I save a session, I get the error `lwsm: save Test UNKNOWN ERROR` (`Test` is the session name I gave).

Here is the output from running lwsm in a terminal:

```
lwsm: no config file present or it contains invalid json. Creating new one...
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/linux-window-session-manager/lib/utility.js:57
      throw err;
      ^

ReferenceError: fs is not defined
    at Object.mkdirSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/linux-window-session-manager/lib/utility.js:54:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/linux-window-session-manager/lib/index.js:33:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/linux-window-session-manager/cmd.js:3:14)
```

Comment: @Xen2050 Sorry. Forgot to specify: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I don't understand your second question. The extension appears, but does not do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a permanent fix, but as a workaround, I found that if you edit `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/linux-window-session-manager/lib/utility.js` and add

```
const fs = require('fs');
```

at the top, then `lwsm` should work for you.

Comment: Indeed! I find it very strange that no one asked about this issue before.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I was a bit surprised by that, myself, when I found your question after having exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the troubleshooting guide on the github page:
https://github.com/johannesjo/linux-window-session-manager

I had the same issue. to fix it i followed the instuctions from the link above and added the program names and commands to the ~/.lwsm/config.json

For example:

if Sublime Text 3 didnt open, I added to the WM_CLASS_AND_EXECUTABLE_FILE:{

this:

```
"subl3.Subl3": "subl3"
```

The first part is the name of the application and the second part is the command that it should run to open it.

Dont forget the "," at the end of the previous entry in the json.

You also have to update the saved session after you change the config.json